# Missing number, treated as zero. (custom class)

Tags: missing, number

I am trying to write a class for science bowl question packets.
For some reason, `\switchletter` works as intended, but an effectively identical use inside `\printmc` does not.

Error message:

```
/testing.tex:9: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.9 ...{Choice W}{Choice X}{Choice Y}{Choice Z}{2}
```

`testing.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{scibowlset}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\newcounter{qnumber}\stepcounter{qnumber}
\switchletter{Choice W}{Choice X}{Choice Y}{Choice Z}{1}
\printmc{Choice W}{Choice X}{Choice Y}{Choice Z}{2}
\end{document}
```

`scibowlset.cls`:

```latex
\ProvidesClass{scibowlset}

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\nofiles

\def \numtoletter #1 {
    \ifcase #1
        \or W
        \or X
        \or Y
        \or Z
    \fi
}

\def \switchletter #1#2#3#4#5 {
    \ifcase #5
        \or #1
        \or #2
        \or #3
        \or #4
    \fi
}

\def \printmc #1#2#3#4#5 {
    % \printmc {<choice w text>}{<choice x text>}{<choice y text>}{<choice z text>}{<correct choice index from 1>}
    \begingroup
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*),start=23]
            \item #1
            \item #2
            \item #3
            \item #4
        \end{enumerate}
    \endgroup
    ANSWER: \numtoletter{#5}) \switchletter{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
}
```

Comment: I realize this code isn't well abstracted (I could probably use \switchletter inside \numtoletter), but I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX is not “free form”.

```latex
%%% file scibowlset.cls
\ProvidesClass{scibowlset}

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\nofiles

\def\numtoletter#1{%
    \ifcase #1
        \or W%
        \or X%
        \or Y%
        \or Z%
    \fi
}

\def\switchletter#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \ifcase #5
        \or #1%
        \or #2%
        \or #3%
        \or #4%
    \fi
}

\def\printmc#1#2#3#4#5{%
    % \printmc {<choice w text>}{<choice x text>}{<choice y text>}{<choice z text>}{<correct choice index from 1>}
    \begingroup
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*),start=23]
            \item #1
            \item #2
            \item #3
            \item #4
        \end{enumerate}
    \endgroup
    ANSWER: \numtoletter{#5}) \switchletter{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
}
```

On the other hand you should do

```latex
\newcommand{\numtoletter}[1]{%
  ...
}
\newcommand{\switchletter}[5]{%
  ...
}
\newcommand{\printmc}[5]{%
  ...
}
```

With your code, TeX expects a space after the trailing argument to the three macros. Beware also that end-of-lines produce a space.

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Comment: At some point earlier, I think I used \def instead of \newcommand because of "missing \begin{document}" errors.